# Geodesic Ball on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with Riemannian Metrics that only depends on $r$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I am having a problem that deals with the metric  on $\mathbb{R}^2$ parametrized with polar coordinate $g=dr^2+f(r)^2d\theta^2$ for some $f$ such that $f(0)=0,f'(0)>0,f(r)>0$ for $r>0$. It asks me to show that the circle $S_\rho$,$r=\rho$ is the geodesic ball with radius $\rho$. It makes sense to me that a usual circle should be a geodesic ball since the metric is independent of $\theta$. But what makes me confused is about how to show that it is indeed with the same radius as the unit circle in tangent space. Is there any way to do this except for solving the geodesic equation explicitly?

Comment: I don't think such a metric is possible. Since the radius of the sphere is constant $f$ would be constant implying the metric is constant over the entire sphere. But the sphere has curvature... A constant metric implies (I think??) that the underlying space is flat.

Comment: @ K.defaoite I think we are considering the metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $S^2$. The geodesic ball, in this case, is definitely homeomorphic to $S^1$

Comment: First, please do not confuse ball and circle. It just muddies the waters. I think you've confused @K.defaoite, in particular. The circle of radius $\rho$ has constant curvature, but so what? Given the metric, how far do I travel with $\theta$ fixed and $r$ varying from $0$ to $\rho$? Indeed, the sphere is an excellent example to understand.